# Copy and paste from Microsoft Excel to ArcGIS 10.1 is not showing pivot table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, table, excel

When I work on my pivot table in MS Excel 2013 and made a copy of it and paste to my ArcGIS 10.1. Why does it not showing ? Is there a work around to make it work ?

Comment: Problem solved !  If you are trying to display it in ArcGIS, do not copy and paste from Excel. Copy to OneNote and then copy from there to ArcGIS. It works !

Comment: Now the Problem when you export the Layout to PDF. The graphic I pasted does not show. Is there something I need to know to make the graphic show on the PDF ?

Comment: Ahhh I am thinking is that we have Microsoft Office 2013 and perhaps that ArcGIS 10.1 is not compatible to read it ? To make it summay, I created a chart from Excel 2013 and copy and paste to ArcGIS 10.1 . So perhaps it does NOT read ? is there a work around ?

Comment: Please, edit your question to add details provided in comments. Also, what type of chart did you generate in Excel? Why, where and how are you trying to copy it to ArcGIS? Tks.

Comment: @AndreSilva  That was dated in 2015 and I don't remember what I did. Do you need to know if you are working the same thing as I did ? Thanks !

Comment: Actually, this question is unclear to me (apparently it is to you now as well, right?). Besides, it seems unrelated to GIS. I wanted to ask you before casting a close vote; because unanswered questions without a clear scope keep appearing as results from searches and they are often false positives to what people is searching, hence it kind of clutters the site. So best thing is to close it (or even delete). Unless you want to edit with more details (my first comment) and explain how it is GIS related. Tks.

Comment: @AndreSilva  I made the edits and let me know if this is better. If not, I can close it..Thanks !

Comment: Tks, but you didn’t address what I asked. Why would you copy a pivot table to ArcGIS? Is this even possible? Perhaps, describe the full process between what data the pivot table had, and how it was organized (the table structure, show a sample of it). How you saved pivot table results (file format), and how you imported such data to ArcGIS that did not work? Yes, probably you won’t remember how you did it, but in its current format, it is unclear to me (hence, not possible to objectively answer it). But it is not because of me the question will be closed; only if more 4 users want to.